# Two function one after the other when clicked pushbutton - Pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qstackedwidget

I have a little problem with py pyside script. I make a setup wizard and I want to change my current widget in my stackedwidget then make the all installation of librairies etc...

I've tried two solutions:

The first is this one:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: changepage(self, MainWindow))
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: makeinstall(self, MainWindow))
```

and it doesn't work, the window don't change and my installation is launch.

The second is:

```
def changepage(self, MainWindow):
     self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
     makeinstall(self, MainWindow)
```

and it doesn't work too. In the two solutions, the page is changed after the installation (after the end of the function I think).

Did someone have a solution to run two function, one after the other in pyside?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slot connected to the signal is called *synchronously*, so the GUI will not be updated until it returns. There are lots of different ways to solve this, but you can try forcing an update like this:

```
def changepage(self, MainWindow):
    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
```

Or if that doesn't work, try using a single-shot timer to run the installer:

```
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: makeinstall(self, MainWindow))
```

Comment: Perfect, the first solution is working, thanks a lot !! :)